# Spring WS webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive return null

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, jaxb

I'm trying to use Spring WS to invoke a WS but the return to my jaxb class myResponse is null.

1 - My request is correct I logged it and used in SOAPUI and the answer is valid.

2 - Debbuging I discovered that inside the Spring classes I have a answer but without body:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><env:Header/><env:Body/></env:Envelope>
```

3 - I discoved too that the problem is the payload is null and return it.

Above is a part of my code, if you need more information just ask.

```
myResponse =  (MyResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(
            requestConfiguration.getEndpoint(),myRequest, 
        new SoapActionCallback("http://test.com/services/myRequest"));
```

Best Regards

**UPDATE**

I'm using HTTPS but disabling it and I'm forcing use SOAP 1.2.